# sending mail in node.js, nodemailer

Tags: node.js, express, email, nodemailer

I wan to send mail with only **nodemailer**. With out other transport system.
below i have given my configuration.
I didn't received any mail, but response showing the mail is successfully send.

Username: sendbox@name.com

Password: ajsdkasd

Incoming Server: mail.name.com

IMAP Port: 993 POP3 Port: 995

Outgoing Server: mail.name.com

SMTP Port: 465

my node mailer configuration is

```
var Mailer = require("nodemailer");

 var transportar = Mailer.createTransport({
 service: "smtp",
 host: "mail.name.com",
 port: 465,

 auth: {
  user: "sendbox@name.com", 
  pass: "jsdkfjksd",   
 },
 });
```

and

```
    var mailOptions = {
            from: "sendbox@name.com", 
            to: req.body.email, 
            subject: "Email Subjects", 
            html: "<h1>Welcome Reciver</h1>", 
          };
          
          
          const sendEmail =  await transportar.sendMail(mailOptions)
```

the response is

```
"email": {
    "accepted": [
        "name@gmail.com"
    ],
    "rejected": [],
    "envelopeTime": 36,
    "messageTime": 4,
    "messageSize": 311,
    "response": "250 OK id=1jnlkk-0006FS-IO",
    "envelope": {
        "from": "sendbox@name.com",
        "to": [
            "name@gmail.com"
        ]
    },
    "messageId": "<cf7fbe92-c59a-9884-5061-77b95c3dcfba@name.com>"
  },
```

Comment: Have you checked spam folder in your mail?

Comment: Yes, is did . Is there anything wrong in my config.

Comment: service: "smtp",
 host: "mail.name.com",
 port: 465,

Comment: try adding secure: true.. Also, for the email account "sendbox@name.com", does the mail sent using nodemailer comes in the sent mail section?

Comment: How can i configure that mail. original mail is sendbox@company_name.com, client mail.